# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended: Postgres to oracle syntax

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql

I get the SQL error ORA-00933 for the statement below. This parses in postgres, but not in oracle... How should this be formatted for oracle?

Thanks in advance!

```
UPDATE comments 
SET parent_type='report' 
FROM reports 
WHERE comments.parent_id=reports.id;
```

Comment: Please check the manual, the syntax is documented there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10008.htm

Comment: ORACLE doesn't supports `FROM` for the `UPDATE` queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for Oracle:

```
UPDATE Comments
SET parent_type = 'report'
WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT Id FROM Reports)
```

Or if you're trying to set the value equal to a value in another column:

```
UPDATE Comments
SET parent_type = (SELECT FieldName
                   FROM reports
                   WHERE reports.id = Comments.parent_id);
```

This would work with MSSQL:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.parent_type='report' 
FROM Comments c JOIN reports r ON c.parent_id=r.id
```

Good luck.